# How to remove a repeated image from .psd file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have a repeated image in my .psd file. I have a map that contains street numbers and i need to automatically remove all numbers. I am looking for a photoshop tool to remove each number. Is there such a tool? [image]

This is how the map looks like and i would like to highlight one number, say 4, and then remove all 4's from the map.

Comment: are the numbers on a separate layer or are they part of the map image?..

Comment: Hi M.C., welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please add an example image? That might help a lot! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @SaturnsEye the numbers are part of the image.

Comment: Ouch, that's going to be an awkward job! good luck

Comment: Cant you go in the map application and turn of the numbers? Or is this a scan of a physical map?

Comment: It was a scan a physical map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy solution if it is a flat file.

Grab the Eraser Tool, the Brush Tool,  the Clone Stamp tool, etc. and cover things up.

You have to do this **manually**, one by one.